# React Native: this.state of reusable components not expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie of React native and honestly I have just a very basic knowledge of React. I'm developing a sample application in which I make use of [reusable components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) and **ES6** sintax.

I'am experiencing unexpected results when reusing the same component multiple times in the same Scene (I also make use of Navigator). More precisely I can't understand why differents components (of the same type) are apparently conditions each others states.

I'm posting my code for a better understanding.

This is my main page , in which I make use 2 times of the same custom defined component **< TopCategories />** :

***HomeScene.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

import BaseScene from './BaseScene'
import SearchSuggest from '../components/SearchSuggest';
import TopCategories from '../components/TopCategories'

import styles from '../styles'


export default class HomeScene extends BaseScene {
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SearchSuggest
          navigator={this.props.navigator}
        />

        <TopCategories/> //first 

        <TopCategories/> //second

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

These are the details of the inner components used:

***TopCategories.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

import styles from '../styles'
import utility from '../utility'
import serverConnector from '../serverConnector'
import routes from '../routes'

import MenuItemComplex from './MenuItemComplex'

export default class TopCategories extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {categories: []};
    this._fetchContent();
  }


  _updateCategoriesList(rawCategories){
    //store in state.categories array a simplied version of         
    //the contents received from the server

    let simplifiedCategories = [];
    for(i=0; i<rawCategories.length; i++){
      var simpleCat = {};
      simpleCat.id = rawCategories[i].uniqueID;
      simpleCat.name = rawCategories[i].name;
      simplifiedCategories.push(simpleCat);
    }

    this.setState({categories: simplifiedCategories });
  }

  _fetchContent(){
    //fetch content from server in JSON format 
    _topCategories = this;
    serverConnector.call(
      "CATEGORY",
      "FindTopCategories",
      {},
      function(err, json){
        if(err!=null) utility.log("e", err);
        else {
          try{
            _topCategories._updateCategoriesList(json.res.header.body.CatalogGroupView);
          }catch(err){
            utility.log("e", err);
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }

  openCategoryScene(id, name){
    //push on Navigator stack the next route with additional data
    let nextRoute = routes.get("categoriesListFirst");
    nextRoute.passProps = {
      categoryId: id,
      categoryName: name
    };
    this.props.navigate(nextRoute)
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <MenuItemComplex key="categories" name="Catalogo" icon="list-b" onItemSelected={this.openCategoryScene.bind(this)} subItems={this.state.categories} />
    )
  }
}
```

and finally 
***MenuItemComplex.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableHighlight, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

import styles from '../styles'

export default class MenuItemComplex extends Component{

  static propTypes = {
    name : React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    icon : React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    subItems: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onItemSelected: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render(){
    let subItems = [];
    for(i=0; i<this.props.subItems.length; i++){
      let subItem = this.props.subItems[i];
      subItems.push(
        <TouchableHighlight
          key={subItem.id}
          underlayColor={"#d00"}
          activeOpacity={1}
          onPress={() => this.props.onItemSelected(subItem.id, subItem.name)}
        >
          <View style={styles.menuSubItem}>
            <Text style={[styles.mmText, styles.menuSubItemText]} >
                {subItem.name}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )
    }

    return(

      <View>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback disabled={true}>
          <View style={styles.menuItem}>
            <Image style={styles.menuItemImage} source={{uri: this.props.icon}} />
            <Text style={[styles.mmTextBold, styles.menuItemText]}>{this.props.name}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

        {subItems}

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I can't understand why the state.simplifiedCategories of the first < TopCategories > component used in my HomeScene seems to be an empty array after the second < TopCategories > component has rendered. So far I thought that the two components were completely isolated, with their own "private" state. But in this case seems that this is shared somehow.

Can someone explain what is happening here ? And then how can I fix that ?

Thanks

**EDIT 2016/09/05**
As suggested by user V-SHY I tried to give every component a randomic string as key, but this does not solve the problem. 
What I find very strange is that I can see only an instance of < TopCategories > in the global window object, the last one.

The screenshot here refers to a test made with

```
 <TopCategories key="tc_first" {...this.props}/>

 <TopCategories key="tc_second" {...this.props}/>
```

in the ***HomeScene.js*** file

[image: console.log(window) result]

Comment: Try to give different key for <TopCategories> components in HomeScene? And try to give dynamic key instead constant key of "categories" for MenuItemComplex component in TopCategories render() ? Seem like , the state of first <TopCategories> component  is reset when the second <TopCategories> component start to render, you render two MenuItemComplex component with same key, and I wonder it is the root of your problem.

Comment: Hi V-SHY, I tried your suggest without success. in particular I tried to give every child component a random string as key, but this doesn't solve the issue. I'm updating the original question adding information about console.log(window)

Comment: If they have separate keys this behaviour can not happen, especially when you have no variables in the file itself. I would suggest giving them a different prop value to distinguish them and then add console.logs to debug what is going on. I would suggest that this is either a problem with data fetching or with mutation.

Comment: Thank you @DanielSchmidt ! it was indeed a problem bound to the fetch mechanism of data from the server. I'm updating the question with the problem and my solution

Comment: @AndreaDiLisio Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel there was an issue during the fetch of data from server. In particular I was wrong when creating a _topCategories=this object inside ***TopCategories.js*** file

```
_fetchContent(){
    _topCategories = this; // ISSUE HERE!
    serverConnector.call(
      "CATEGORY",
      "FindTopCategories",
      {},
      function(err, json){
        if(err!=null) utility.log("e", err);
        else {
          try{
            _topCategories._updateCategoriesList(json.res.header.body.CatalogGroupView);
          }catch(err){
            utility.log("e", err);
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

I solved passing the fetchContent method a reference of the component :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {categories: []};
    this._fetchContent(this); // passing THIS reference
  }


  _updateCategoriesList(rawCategories){
    let simplifiedCategories = [];
    for(i=0; i<rawCategories.length; i++){
      var simpleCat = {};
      simpleCat.id = rawCategories[i].uniqueID;
      simpleCat.name = rawCategories[i].name;
      simplifiedCategories.push(simpleCat);
    }

    this.setState({categories: simplifiedCategories});
  }

  _fetchContent(instanceRef){
    motifConnector.call(
      "CATEGORY",
      "FindTopCategories",
      {},
      function(err, json){
        if(err!=null) utility.log("e", err);
        else {
          try{
            instanceRef._updateCategoriesList(json.res.header.body.CatalogGroupView);
          }catch(err){
            utility.log("e", err);
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: how about ```this._fetchContent = this._fetchContent.bind(this);```  in constructor and then ```this._updateCategoriesList(json.res.header.body.CatalogGroupView);``` in try statement of _fetchContent() function?

Refer to Step 3 - Bind instance methods / callbacks to the instance from http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes